# Unable to fetch data with axios from Django backend using relative path

Tags: reactjs, django, docker

I am currently developing a web application using React for my frontend and Django for my backend. The frontend and backend are running on separate local servers.

I am trying to fetch some data from my Django backend using axios in my React application with the following code:

```
const handleButtonClick = () => {
    setLoading(true);
    axios
        .get("/bucket-size/")
        .then((response) => {
            const size = response.data.bucketsize;
            const unit = response.data.unit;
            setOutput(size + " " + unit);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        })
        .finally(() => {
            setLoading(false);
        });
};
```

The Django backend route looks like this:

```
path('bucket-size/', BucketSize.as_view(), name='bucket-size'),
```

Note -- i do not want to add a proxy to my package.json since the backend will be running on Docker and i want it to fetch relatively.
Can anyone help?

Comment: are you getting any errors? 404? 500? what does `response` look like iinside the `.then()` method? is anything coming back?